# Synchronized (and volatile) not working as expected after screen off/on

Tags: java, android, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a class with an instance that is used by two threads. The method called from one thread is:

```
private Object sync1 = new Object();
private int state;
@Override
protected void onEnabled()  
{
    synchronized (sync1){
        state = getState();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onEnabled() " + state );
}
```

and from the other:

```
@Override
public void onF1() {
    int lState;
    synchronized (sync1){
        lState = state;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onF1 state " + lState);
}
```

When starting the app, it works fine, but after turning off/on the screen by pressing the power button, I get the following output in the logcat:

```
16279-16788 I/MyClass: onEnabled() 1 
16279-16372 I/MyClass: onF1 state 0
```

The threads are much heavier, and probably they run on different cores of the device. I originally tried to use volatile for the state, and then went to synchronized. Any clues why state is not 1 in onF1 method?

Edit 1: I checked hash on classloader and it is the same before/after. The object address is also the same. I also tried to put a field breakpoint on the variable.

Comment: Could you please make sure that you are not re-instantiating anything in your Activity.onResume() or .onStart()?

Comment: why did you remove `volatile`?

Comment: also, do `onEnabled()` and on `onF1()` belong to the same class? can you show more code of such class?

Comment: @payloc: Yes, the TAG from the logcat shows the name of the class. I changed volatile with synchronized block.

Comment: @RobertK. How can I make sure? For example I checked hash on classloader and it is the same before/after. The object address is also the same. I also tried to put a field breakpoint on the variable.

Comment: stupid question, but can you prove that the instance is the same for both threads and you are not calling the methods of two different objects?

Comment: @payloc Actually it is a good question. Actually I checked this once, and the reference seemed the same. In the meantime I run more tests and it seems that the second thread was leaking a reference to the initial instance. After the off/on, I was recreating the object, but the second thread used its reference.

Comment: you should then set the instance as `volatile` in order to keep all threads' cache up to the date: `private volatile MyClass myClass;`

Comment: @payloc: I'll add an answer, as I discovered it prior to reading your comment. But thanks for your time. I'll reward voyager. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second thread leaked a reference to the object, so after the turn off/on of the screen, when the Object was recreated, the threads had different instances of the class. With subsequent tests, the address of the object was different for the threads.